# Как передать 2 объекта разных структур в шаблон?

Tags: веб-программирование, golang, веб-сервер

Как передать в шаблон сразу 2 объекта разных структур и как в этом случае потом правильно вызывать данные в шаблоне? (Подойдёт пример без цикла). Не хочется костылить и делать общую структуру для этих 2 структур. Хочется нормального решения.

```golang
type Excursion struct {
    ID    int
    Value string
}

type ExGroup struct {
    ID          int
    Description string
}

p1 := Excursion{}
p2 := ExGroup{}

tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("admin/template.html")
_ = tmpl.Execute(w, p1, p2)
```

Comment: Не обращайте внимание на то, что объекты структур пустые. Я пропустил этап заполнения в примере, что бы не загромождать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, почему вы называете создание новой структуры «костылём», не говоря уже о том, что непонятно, как вы хотите обращаться к полям структуры в шаблоне. Вот вам два варианта:

1. Анонимная структура:

   ```golang
   var v = struct {
       P1 Excursion
       P2 ExGroup
   }{
       P1: p1,
       P2: p2,
   }

   err = tmpl.Execute(w, v)
   ```
2. Хеш-таблица:

   ```golang
   var m = map[string]interface{}{
       "p1": p1,
       "p2": p2,
   }

   err = tmpl.Execute(w, m)
   ```

Comment: В вашем случае новая структура - не костыль, так как вы сделали вложенную структуру, а я думал просто скопировать все поля из первой и второй структуры и вставить их все в третью. Все оказалось проще, чем я думал. Спасибо вам. Но как мне в данном случае вызывать нужные поля в шаблоне? Если структура была не вложенная, то это делалось так: {{.Id}}, {{.Description}}. Теперь, когда структура вложенная, вероятно, это делается вот так: {{P1.Id}}, {{P2.Description}} ?

Comment: Почти. Будет `{{.P1.Id}}`, и т. д.